# Firebase Storage pricing terms explanation

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Would like get more info of what each term exactly means and how can I effectively use the calculator to best estimate my costs given the following scenario

1. 1 GB of photos uploaded to Firebase Storage in one go.
2. These photos are viewed by approx 10,000 users per month.

Can someone please detail what parameters of the calculator will be used in the given case.

[image]

Comment: The cost depends on how many users see how many pictures and how big those pictures are. Only you can estimate that.

Comment: Can you help me with the calculation given the above scenario and 1 MB per image size? I just want to be clear with the basics of this calculation

Comment: How many times does each user download an image? `bandwidth = #users * #number_of_images_downloaded * size_of_image`

Comment: And this is the GB Transferred metric if I understand you right? Thanks for the help @FrankvanPuffelen